# How to Change Selected Radio Button Symbol ("X") in Completed Docusign document

Tags: docusignapi

After completed signing the document.Selected radio buttons and checkboxes are shown as "X" in the completed document.Can we change this "X" symbol to tick mark or something else.Kindly find the Image attached.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in DoucSign to customize how the checked radio buttons appears.

Also note that, once a document has been signed no changes can be made to it.